# when is the defintion of a function checked in class?

Tags: c++, function, inheritance

```
class A
{
    public:
    int fun1();
    int fun2();
    void sum()
    {
        cout<<fun1()+fun2();
    }
};
class B: public A
{
    int fun1()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    int fun2()
    {
        return 2;
    }
};
int main()
{
    A x;
    B y;
    x.sum();// line 3
    y.sum();// line 4
    return 0;
}
```

Why there is error now?? and 
Why there is no errors if line 3, line4 are missing?
How does the sequence of checks performed?
**EDIT**
 why doesn't the compiler generate error though there is error when a call to x.sum() is made

Comment: Where do you defined `fun1` and `fun2` for `A`?

Comment: Adding `int A::func1() { return 0; }` `int A::func2() { return 0; }` will solve your link issue.

Comment: "Why there is error now?" - What error? You don't show us any error message. We are not mind readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why there is error now??

Because you have not defined them.

> and Why there is no errors if line 3, line4 are missing?

If lines 3 and 4 are missing, `A::sum()` is not used. Hence, its definition is not looked up. `A::fun1()` and `A::fun2()` are used only by `A::sum()`. Since no other function uses `A::fun1()` and `A::fun2()`, their definitions are not looked up either.

When you have lines and 3 and 4, The definition of `A::sum()` is looked up at link time. Since `A::sum()` uses `A::fun1()` and `A::fun2()`, their definitions are looked up too.

> How does the sequence of checks performed?

A function can be used in a statement/expression as long as it declared. It is a link time error not to define them.

A function may be declared but not defined if it is not used.

Comment: *If lines 3 and 4 are missing the line after that will fail to compile. When you have lines and 3 and 4, you are telling the compiler: "Here are the declarations. Use them. I will define them later."* That's not right.  When lines 3 and 4 (note that those lines are commented as line 3 and line 4) then there is no compiler or linker error.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I misunderstood the meaning of lines 3 and lines 4. Let me update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A function declaration tells the compiler about a function's name, return type, and parameters. A function definition provides the actual body of the function.
The general form of a C++ function definition is as follows:

```
return_type function_name( parameter list ) {
   body of the function
}
```

If functions are not defined (**return_type**) in your case, it will give you errors.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your last sentence. What return_type is missing?